# How to reload a page without selecting reload option?

Tags: javascript

I use `location.reload(true);` in order to reload updated value from service. It is working, but only when I reload the browser. Is there any other way to reload the page without this window displays?

Comment: We need more information; in most normal situations this should work out of the box. How are values retrieved from the server? Are they part of the base HTML page, or retrieved after loading? Do you get any information from the Network tab of your browser's developer tools?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `apply` to digest the changes and refresh the page.

see this [blog](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html) for reference. it has a very nice example to illustrate too.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to apply to angular as far as I can tell.